# One of the following statements is true and one is false: If xy and x are both rational, then y is too....

Tags: discrete-mathematics

One of the following statements is true and one is false:

- If xy and x are both rational, then y is too.
- If x − y and x are both rational, then y is too.

I was able to find a proof for the first statement:

```
xy= ab/cd x=a/b, then y=ad/cbx -> y=adb/cba -> y=d/c -> y is rational, therefore statement is true.
```

However, I cannot find any ways to disprove the second statement. Is it even possible for any of these statements to be false?

Comment: Hint: If $x=0$ then $xy=0$

Comment: Notice your proof involves division by a variable ($x$) that very well could be zero. If you added the hypothesis that $x \neq 0$, then your proof is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proof" you have for the first one is incorrect, and it is actually the second statement that is correct.

Indeed, the second statement is correct since, if $a,b\in\mathbb Q$, then $a-b\in\mathbb Q$. So try $a=x$ and $b=x-y$.

However, the first statement is false because we can take $x=0$ and $y$ as any irrational number. Your first proof works if we assume $x\neq 0$, because you multiply by the inverse $\frac{b}{a}$, but if $x=0$ then $a=0$ so we would be dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement:

If $xy$ and $x$ are both rational, then $y$ is too.

As Dave mentioned, taking $x=0$ which implies $xy=0$ can let us choose $y$ any irrational number, say $y=\pi$, to form a counterexample.

The second statement:

If $x − y$ and $x$ are both rational, then $y$ is too.

Since $x$ is a rational number, we can write it as a ratio of two integers, say $a$ and $b$. $x-y$ is also a rational number, so it can be written as $\frac{c}{d}$ where $c$ and $d$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}$. So far we have:
$$x = \frac{a}{b}$$
and
$$x-y = \frac{c}{d}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{a}{b} - y = \frac{c}{d}$$
$$y = \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}$$
$$y = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$
By properties of integers $ad$, $bc$, $ad-bc$ and $bd$ are all integers. Replacing $ad-bc$ with $e$ and $bd$ with $f$ ($e,f \in \mathbb{Z})$, it can be concluded that $y=\frac{e}{f}$ which means $y$ is a rational number.